# Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Subspace of $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces, function-spaces

Let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on a non-empty Borel subset $X\subseteq (0,\infty)$.  The space $H\subseteq C(X;\mathbb{R})$ such that every element of $H$ can be identified with an element of $ L_{\mu}^2(X)$; where $X$ is equipped with the relative topology on $X$ induced by restriction from $(0,\infty)$.

Fix a distinguised point $x^{\star}\in X$.  If we define the inner-product on $H$ to be
$$
\left\langle f,g \right\rangle\triangleq f(x^{\star})g(x^{\star}) + \int_{x \in X} f(x)g(x) \, d\mu(x),
$$
then does $H$ admit an (infinite-dimenional) RKHS subspace?

Comment: What is $f(0)$ for $f \in L^2_{\mu}(X)$?

Comment: I did not notice this, but you are right, a well-chosen indicator function does the trick.  Let me adjust my question; thanks harp.